# In the example regression, which is the target column?

Tags: lightgbm

I have run the example/regression here
https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/examples/regression

One simple question is which colume in `regression.train` and `regression.test` is the feature and which column is used as target?

Answer (score 0):

When using the LightGBM command-line interface (CLI), if you do not provide a value for the parameter `label_column` in `train.conf`, then the first column in the training data will be used as the target.

This can be seen in the source code for `DatasetLoader`, the class LightGBM uses to create a LightGBM `Dataset` object from a file.

- `label_idx_` ("column to use for the target") is initialized to 0: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/a8ee487aca35363fafa027e6b7695976045096b3/src/io/dataset_loader.cpp#L22
- `label_idx_` is only overridden if `label_column` is provided in the config: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/a8ee487aca35363fafa027e6b7695976045096b3/src/io/dataset_loader.cpp#L48